# ¿Por qué mi consulta de MySQLi no muestra el primer registro?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente tabla en una base de datos:
[image: Base de datos]

Y con el siguiente bloque de código mando a llamar los datos

```
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registro_sanciones");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $json = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $json[] = array(
            'ID' => $row['ID'],
            'PlayerID' => $row['PlayerID'],
            'JNombre' => $row['JNombre'],
            'Fecha' => $row['Fecha'],
            'Datos' => $row['Datos']
        );
    }

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
```

El problema es que sólo me muestra los 3 últimos registros, no el primero.
[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas haciendo `$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);` justo antes de declarar la variable `$json = array();`

#### Solución:

Saca esa línea.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registro_sanciones");
$json = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $json[] = array(
        'ID' => $row['ID'],
        'PlayerID' => $row['PlayerID'],
        'JNombre' => $row['JNombre'],
        'Fecha' => $row['Fecha'],
        'Datos' => $row['Datos']
    );
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

---

#### Actualización

Algunas veces las cosas se pueden simplificar, lo que ayuda a la legibilidad del código y (*en un mundo ideal*) a cometer menos errores.

Tu código redunda en el nombre de los datos de cada registro y en la intención de devolver todos los datos obtenidos en la consulta.

Esto es un indicio de que se puede simplificar, por ejemplo, así:

- Traer en la consulta los datos (*las columnas*) justos y necesarios (*y con el nombre que se espera [`eg: alias`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/)*)

  ```
  SELECT ID, PlayerID, JNombre, Fecha, Datos
  FROM registro_sanciones
  ```
- Si no hace falta controlar uno por uno los registros obtenidos, entonces se puede utilizar [`mysqli_fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)(*solo disponible con `mysqlnd`*) para obtener todos.
- **Recomendación**: si es un `JSON` lo que se devuelve, es recomendable indicarlo estableciendo el [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) correspondiente.

Entonces, tu código podría escribirse así:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID, PlayerID, JNombre, Fecha, Datos FROM registro_sanciones");
$records = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($records);
```

Comment: El código se puede simplificar muchísimo mas. Si te interesa, comenta aquí así actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, Marcos. No pensé que afectase esa línea, igual no tenía uso, jaja.
¿A qué te refieres con simplificar más?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMarrufo, con simplificar me refiero que se puede lograr el mismo resultado con menos código

Comment: Marcos, te recomiendo dejar el codigo actual como respuesta y adicional el otro codigo reducido, asi le das una idea a Carlos.

Comment: @ByGroxD, gracias por comentar, efectivamente era lo que pensaba a hacer.

Comment: Marcos, ¿me puedes ayudar a simplificarlo?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMarrufo, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, Marcos. Lo tendré muy en cuenta para modificar.